# How do I count up the number of letter pairs in python?

Tags: python

I am making a program in python that count up the number of letter pairs.
For example ------> 'ddogccatppig' will print 3, 'a' will print 0, 'dogcatpig' will print 0, 'aaaa' will print 3, and 'AAAAAAAAAA' will print 9.
My teacher told me to use a for loop to get the i and i+1 index to compare. I do not know how to do this, and I am really confused. My code:

```
def count_pairs( word ):

  pairs = 0
  chars = set(word)

  for char in chars:
      pairs += word.count(char + char)

  return pairs
```

Please help me!!! Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't "AAAAAAAAAA" be 9?

Comment: Yes, I'm so sorry. I thought I typed 9. I'll fix it

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop is only to iterate through the appropriate values of `i`, not *directly* to do the comparison.  You need to start `i` at 0, and iterate through `i+1` being the last index in the string.  Work this out on paper.

Alternately, use `i-1` and `i`; then you want to start `i-1` at 0, which takes less typing:

```
for i in range(1, len(word)):
    if word[i] == word[i-1]:
        ...
```

Even better, don't use the counter at all -- make a list of equality results and count the `True` values:

```
return sum([word[i] == word[i-1] for i in range(1, len(word))])
```

This is a bit of a "dirty trick" using the fact that `True` evaluates as 1 and `False` as 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop over indices instead of the actual characters, you can do:

```
for i in range(len(word)):
    # do something with word[i] and/or word[i+1] or word[i-1]
```

Converting the string to a set first is counterproductive because it removes the ordering **and** the duplicates, making the entire problem impossible for two different reasons.  :)

Comment: Don't forget to check if `i+1` is in bounds or not

Comment: @afghanimah: spoilers!!!  ;)  `IndexError`s build character.  If we didn't want to walk off the edge we'd have just modified our `range`...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer:

```
test = "ddogccatppig"

def count_pairs(test):
  counter = 0
  for i in range(0,len(test)-1):
    if test[i] == test[i+1]
      counter+=1
  return counter

print(count_pairs(test))
```

Here you iterate through the length of the string (minus 1 because otherwise you will get an index out of bounds exception). Add to a counter if the letter is the same as the one in front and return it.

Answer (score 0):

This is another (similar) way to get the same answer.

```
def charPairs(word):
    word = list(word)
    count = 0

    for n in range(0, len(word)-1):
        if word[n] == word[n+1]:
            count +=1

    return count
       

print(charPairs("ddogccatppig"))
print(charPairs("a"))
print(charPairs("dogcatpig"))
print(charPairs("aaaa"))
print(charPairs("AAAAAAAAAA"))
```